# How to change 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' using curl command in restapi?

Tags: shell

Any one help me how to change 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' format.

header='-H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer '$token'" -H "x-api-key: '$key'"'
   data='-d "{"image": "https://example.com/demo/img/hd-001.jpg"}"'
URL=https://variant.example.com/api/vi

i want to change content type to image/jpeg format.

i am getting bellow error.
{
"invalid_body",
body."
}
400: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{

Comment: The `Content-Type` header describes the data. It makes no sense to change it without changing the data. It is provided by your HTTP server. Please read more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) then improve your question to give some [MCVE]

Comment: What do you want to do? What have you tried so far? What is the error message or output? Give more details before anyone can help you.

Comment: Execution result: {
  "error" : {
    "code" : "invalid_body",
    "message" : "An invalid value was specified in the request body."
  }
}Response_Time 1.420 Response_Code 400